# R-Graphs: exclude non-relevant values from axis

Tags: r, boxplot, r-factor

have something alike. I have a dataset with 22000 values and want to show them in a proper way (with my data: a graph for every river with the fish species cought in this river on the y-axis and the number of fish caught per species on the x-axis.

```
dat<-file[file$RiverName=="Mississippi",]

boxplot(FishCought ~ FishName, cex.axis=0.7, horizontal=TRUE, las=2, col="green", xlab="Abundanz [Ind./ha]")
```

If I do so, the Graph shows all "Fishname"s on the y-Axis, only drawing a boxplot at those fish which were caught in this River.... how can I get rid of those Fish Names that aren't caught in this river (to make the graph better-looking)?!

Any suggestions?

Comment: is that really the code you are running? data$FishCought and dat$FishName? pls fix, and you can use boxplot(FishCought ~ FishName, data = data) in order to easily avoid simple mistakes like these (if that is the intention)

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that `FishCought` is actually `FishCaught`... The syntax would be

```
boxplot(FishCaught ~ FishName, data =
        within(subset(file, RiverName=="Mississippi" & FishCaught > 0),
               FishName <- factor(FishName)))
```

`subset(file, RiverName=="Mississippi" & FishCaught > 0)` selects only the samples you want.

`within(...,FishName <- factor(FishName))` returns a data frame with `FishName` as a categorical variable where fish not caught in this river is not included as a category (or "factor level" in R parlance).

Comment: I edited the question but did not change the spelling of "cought" since the questioner spelled in that way in the text body as well. Agree your method should solve his problem.